# "High Definition Audio Device" missing

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, windows-10-v1703

I reinstalled Windows 10 on my laptop. It defaulted to installing Realtek's sound drivers, but due to a well-reported defect in those drivers, microphone audio input has an absurdly low volume when used with Skype.

Ordinarily, I downgrade the drivers manually to the "High Definition Audio Device" drivers. However, on this installation of Windows, those drivers appear to be missing:

[image: Window with missing driver]

How do I get the driver back?

Comment: Download them from the manufacturers' website. They often make modifications to those drivers to suit the devices in your laptop.

Comment: @GiantTree The Realtek drivers for my laptop are defective, no matter where you get them. Its a well-documented issue for the Dell XPS 15 9530. I've tried from Dell directly, from Realtek, and the Windows Update versions, again and again every time I reformat for years. The only drivers that work are the generic HD Audio drivers.